# Assembly.GetTypes() does not return types that implement an interface defined elsewhere

Tags: c#, reflection, t4

I am working to create a list of all implementations of a specific interface in my application and I'm trying to do this by reflection in a T4 Template, using it to generate C#.

I have some code that looks like this:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\..\Project2\bin\project1.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\..\Project2\bin\project2.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="Project1.Interfaces" #>
<#
    string assemblyPath1 = this.Host.ResolvePath("..\\Project2\\bin\\project1.dll");
    string assemblyPath2 = this.Host.ResolvePath("..\\Project2\\bin\\project2.dll");
    var type = typeof(Project1.Interfaces.IAction);
    var types1 = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath1).GetTypes()
                .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass).ToList();
    var types2 = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath2).GetTypes()
                .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass).ToList();
#>
```

Obviously the real version does a lot more and you can assume that if you can't see an `import` directive I have omitted it here for brevity and readability. but as far as I can tell this is where the problem arises. The `types1` variable will contain a list of a whole lot of `IAction` implementations, but the `types2` list will be empty, in spite of the fact that I have Project2 open right in front of me and  it definitely contains several public types that implement `IAction` .

From what I can tell looking at the documentation, this is probably because the `IAction` interface is defined in Project1 and there can be problems with `GetTypes()` related to assemblies being loaded when it is called. However, as far as I can tell the actual call is running smoothly- I'm not seeing a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` being thrown - it just does not find those interface implementations. If I list the names of everything returned in the `types2` collection, those class names are absent from the list.

What do I need to do in order to be able to find the implementations of the `IAction` interface in my second assembly?

Comment: Sure, project2 was probably not built with a reference to Project1.Interfaces and uses its own IAction interface definition.  Can't work, type identity in .NET is not just namespace+typename, it also includes the assembly in which it is defined.

Comment: Project2 contains a reference to the Project1 dlls and Project1.Interfaces is referenced in the relevant classes. I don't know much about the internals here- would Project2 somehow create a different version or copy of IAction internally that masks the Project1 original?

Comment: Yes, that is not unlikely.  We don't know anything about the DLL that contains IAction.  Maybe you have more than one copy of it.  Troubleshoot with Fuslogvw.exe, log all binds so you can see it getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments from Hans Passant, I was able to resolve this problem by making sure I used the copies of the dlls that belonged in the same dependency chain, rather than using ones that had come from different sources ( by choosing which output folders I took them from ) at which point all the implementations of the interface showed up in my collections.

Hopefully this can help anyone who runs into the same problem but it would be great to get an answer that details more about the exact process that leads to the problem.